# Coreldraw VBA GlobalMacroStorage: How to close active document after open?

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I need to automate some process. I wrote some code to publish cdr files as PDF:

```
Sub GlobalMacroStorage_DocumentOpen(ByVal doc As Document, ByVal FileName As String)    
Set doc = ActiveDocument
With doc.PDFSettings
...{some code here}
.Linearize = True
.PageRange = "1,2"
.pdfVersion = pdfVersion13
.PublishRange = pdfPageRange
.TrueTypeToType1 = True
.TextAsCurves = True
.OverprintBlackLimit = True
End With

If Len(Dir(doc.FilePath + "\coreltmp", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir doc.FilePath + "coreltmp"
End If
name2 = Dir(FileName) + "TEST.pdf"
 strName = doc.FilePath & "coreltmp" & "\" & name2
doc.PublishToPDF strName
ActiveDocument.Close  <<=====ERROR LINE
End Sub
```

Marked line makes error: the document cannot be closed from the document event handler . So the question is: how close this document without close whole application?

Comment: It could be that you are trying to close the document before it's done processing the PDF. Try putting a messagebox in before ActiveDocument.Close  <<=====ERROR LINE, and wait 5 or ten seconds to close it. That should create a seperate thread and allow enough time for PDF to process. If you don't get the error then that's the issue.

Comment: I remove PDF_publish code from this macro to another: "pdf_exporter". Now in this macro I've got "call pdf_exporter".  When I run it manually it works, but in auto mode PDF create is ok but it don't close document (it works without error message, everything is ok, but document is still open)

Comment: On open, you want to close the document?  Wouldn't that make it impossible to open a document?

Answer (score 0):

In you case **doc** = **ActiveDocument**.
Just simply use:

```
doc.Close
```